# The letters won't appear in VScode (Ubuntu 20.04, M1 pro(arm64))

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgK2r.png)

I can't see the letter of the VScode like the image. VScode has been installed in Debian arm64. How can I fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue running Ubuntu 20.04 in UTM 4.0.9 on the M1 apple silicon. Starting visual studio code from the command line like this soled it.

```
code  --disable-gpu
```

There is a discussion in github about this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161681